# GEE results showing opposite of true marginal relationship with EXCH working correlation

Tags: repeated-measures, sas, generalized-estimating-equations, genmod

I am working on a modelling issue with two main effect variables: time period and Setting, related to an outcome, with all 3 being binary. My PI wants to test for moderating effects, so we have an interaction term included. There are repeated measures within individuals in the study. I have to code it in SAS but it is not my preferred language.

This is my SAS code:

```
PROC GENMOD Data=lib.modeldata;
CLASS Study_ID Setting Period Outcome;
MODEL Outcome=period Setting period*setting / dist=binomial link=log;
repeated subject=Study_ID/type=EXCH;
RUN;
```

This is run over ~80000 obs, with about 14000 unique Study IDs.

When I run the model with this structure, it returns model parameters that have totally wild values out of line with the direction/magnitude of my contingency tables. When I run the same model with type=IND (i.e. assuming no clustering) the coefficient values are in line with the data and quite different.

Questions:

1. I thought misspecifying the correlation structure would not shift marginal estimates?
2. What could cause this? Is my model not converging?

I would really appreciate any answers or article links. I have done a good amount of reading and am unsure how this is even possible.

Answer (score 0):

If the model is correctly specified, in the sense that
$$E[Y_{it}|\mathbf{X}_i]=\mathbf{X}_i\beta$$
then changing the working correlation structure does not affect the parameter being estimated.  This can go wrong for three related reasons.

The first reason is that the model could just be badly specified. You check this like you would in any regression model.

The second reason is that between-person and within-person associations are different. They are weighted differently by the exchangeable and independence working correlation structures.  To check this, define two variables $X_b$ that might be the baseline values of $X$ for each person and $X_w$ as the differences $X_{it}-X_{bi}$. Do these variables have similar coefficients? ([reference](https://doi.org/10.1177/00220345000790100801))

The third reason is more complicated. The assumption, as I said, is
$$E[Y_{it}|\mathbf{X}_i]=\mathbf{X}_i\beta$$
not
$$E[Y_{it}|X_{it}]={X}_{it}\beta$$

That is, you need the *past* and *future* $X$s to be correctly modelled, not just the current $X$.  In particular, if $Y_{it}$ affects future $X$s, this will probably not be true. Here's the [reference](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/03610919408813210) (and here's a [rediscovery](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2685589) of it)

[note: 'assuming no clustering' is not really a good description of the independence working model, because it doesn't assume no clustering. It's a choice of weights, not an assumption]

Comment: Thank you, that is extremely helpful.

Comment: Thank you again, I did not fully understand the time-dependence assumptions of GEE and this was very educational. I now understand that GMM will likely be more appropriate for this dataset.

Comment: GMMs often have the same assumptions: the phrase "dynamic misspecification" is one example of the issues